# Is there Hadamard product about capital Xi function(Landau-RIemann Xi function)?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-hypothesis

While I was trying to translate Riemann's paper "On the numbers of prime less than a given quantity" into Korean, I've found a strage thing in it.

Riemann wrote on his paper
$$\log\Xi(t)=\sum_{\Xi(\alpha)=0}\log(1- {t^2 \over \alpha^2} )+\log\Xi(0).$$

In fact, he used $\xi$ in stead of $\Xi$, but he defined in his paper $\xi$ as following
$$\xi(t)=(s-1)\Gamma({s \over 2}+1)\pi^{-{s \over 2}}\zeta(s)$$
where $s= {1 \over 2}+it$, so I just use capital Xi.

Anyway, I already knew the Hadamard product about $\xi$ function, which is
$$\xi(s)=\xi(0)\prod_{\rho}(1-{s \over \rho}).$$
but I've never heard of, or seen the product formula about $\Xi$ function. I googled about them, of course, but couldn't get anything. I also guessed that product formula is derived from $\xi$ function Hadamard product, but I was impossible to derive it. Since there was no proof about that product in the paper, so I have no idea how where it came from. Can anybody explain me how to prove it? Or did Riemann jsut use $\xi$ as $(s-1)\Gamma({s\over2}+1)\pi^{-{s\over2}}\zeta(s)$?

Also, since I'm not really good at English(I'm Korean student), I was not able to understand some terms. For example, Riemann said the integral $\int d\log\xi(t)$ is equal to $(T\log{T\over2\pi}-T)i$  up to a fraction of the order of magnitude of the quantity ${1\over T}$. Does that mean that  $\int d\log\xi(t)=(T\log{T\over2\pi}-T)i+O({1\over T})$?

Comment: why don't you look into Edwards book on the subject as he unpacks Riemann's paper in detail and with modern notation there

Comment: Does $\Xi(z)=\xi(0)\prod_{\rho}(1-{{1 \over 2}+i z \over \rho})$ not suit your needs?

Comment: @Conrad, sorry, but can you tell me the name of the book?

Comment: Isn't that just the Hadamard product of small xi function, @StevenClark?

Comment: Since it is a book about Riemann Zeta it is called Riemann's Zeta Function by H Edwards; https://store.doverpublications.com/0486417409.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll read it to understand them better! @Conrad

Comment: I don't understand your question. Isn't it obvious the product formula for $\xi(s)$ also gives a product formula for $\Xi(z)=\xi(\frac{1}{2}+i z)$?

Comment: Ah...well yes, it will give the product for $\Xi$ but, what I meant was that I couldn't derive that product formula on the top from priduct of $\xi$.